# How do I switch UISegmentedControl programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I switch `UISegmentedControl` programmatically?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The [selectedSegmentIndex](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/selectedSegmentIndex) property identifies the selected segment of a UISegmentedControl. Set this property to the any valid segment index, or [UISegmentedControlNoSegment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UISegmentedControlNoSegment) (-1) to turn off the current selection.

```
// select the first segment
segmented.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

// turn off the current selection
segmented.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
```

Comment: This won't actually trigger whatever target/action you have set up for when the user selects a different segment, though.

Comment: @jmstone617 I wouldn't expect that, just like with a UISwitch - at least in my experience, setting it's value from, say, User Defaults does't automatically call whatever function would be called if the user manually changed its state.

Comment: to trigger the action you want write afterwards: segmentedControl.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)

Answer (score 109):

Alternatively, after you have changed the selectedSegmentIndex call 'sendActionsForControlEvents:' for example

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

[segmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

**SWIFT 5:**

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
segmentedControl.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: Without `sendActionsForControlEvents`, it just changes the segment but wont  trigger event. In Swift it is `segmentedControl.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)`  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Working Good but the old index color not changing

Answer (score 29):

In Swift:

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
```

Swift 2:

```
segmentedControl.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Swift 3:

```
segmentedControl.sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Answer (score 25):

@jmstone response,
true, this action will not invoke the valueChanged event for this control.

One way to overcome this is to just call the function yourself:

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 3;
[self valueChangedMethod:segmentedControl];
```

This will call:

```
- (void)valueChangedMethod:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl
{
    //continue your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** as Yogesh Nikam Patil made me notice, UIControlEvents has been renamed from UIControlEvents to UIControl.Event. I've updated my code accordingly.

@arcady bob answer was the one that did the trick for me.

I just post an updated version for **SWIFT 5**:

```
yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
yourSegmentedControl.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

If you use just the first line, the segmented will react accordingly graphically, but your IBAction associated with the segmented control won't be called. In a few words: the second line is like tapping on the segmented control.
This is what I needed and what I was missing.

Comment: 'UIControlEvents' has been renamed to 'UIControl.Event'

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem where the segmented control wasn't changing.
I was calling "selectedSegmentIndex", etc too early. Once I called it after "viewDidLoad" was called then everything was fine again.

Answer (score 3):

First, create an outlet from the segmented control you've added from the UI

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
Using the code below programmatically change the selected segment

segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1 // index