# Select which case is selected for UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using an UISegmentedControl and have a switch with two cases set for each option. As of now the first case is selected when the view controller loads.

EDIT: How would I set the second case to be selected instead of the first only when the count is higher than the first.

Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(_ _collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var count = 0

    switch(filmSeg.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

        count = one.count 

        break

    case 1:

        count = two.count

        break

    default:
        break

    }

    return count

}
```

Comment: The first case applies because `filmSeg.selectedSegmentIndex` is 0. If you don’t like that, change the code or set `filmSeg.selectedSegmentIndex` to something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default state of a UISegmentedControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027424/how-can-i-set-the-default-state-of-a-uisegmentedcontrol)

Comment: This question is for swift 4 and check the updated edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here on [the Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618575-selectedsegmentindex), `selectedSegmentIndex` is declared as such:

```
var selectedSegmentIndex: Int { get set }
```

This means you can just put something like this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
filmSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
```